# Cannot pass try catch block return value within two methods

Tags: java, sql, rest, variables, methods

**This is the code**:

---

[image: This is the code]

```
On top of the question you can see the code. 
This is the first method (cell_data()).It's got the oracle db cell value.
I want to pass the cell_data() return value to  PUTSuccessful_2() method.
Always display the below result.
```

but the result is this:Updated column cell: null

I am using to run the maven test to run this code.  if I am adding a main method db value is get correctly.

```
**This is the result**


Updated column cell: null
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, post the code, not an image, as it is hard to retype it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here. 1. You are getting an exception. Log statement inside the catch block could prove that. 2. The M150_DESCRIPTION column in table is null

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not able to establish **db connection**. Firstly check the db connection and then check whether your query is returning any result or not.

Comment: If i am using main method i can get the result.

Comment: try printing stacktrace in the catch block